# Can R be packaged in an iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, r

I'm aware of efforts to create an R GUI or command line for iOS, but that's not what I'm concerned with.

I'd like to use R and `ggplot2` to create visualizations for an iOS app.

Is this possible? Are there any examples available?

Edit: I'm not sure if "packaged" is the right word. I imagine R itself would have to be incorporated in the app itself – let me know if I'm using the wrong vocabulary here.

Comment: Apple should embrace it: it will make very expensive iPads popular among very special crowd :-)

Comment: realizing that this does not actually answer your question, just want to be sure you are aware of: http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/

Comment: also not an answer to your question, but worth considering is http://www.rforge.net/Rserve/

Answer (score 5):

Each time this question has come up in the past, someone has quoted from the Apple rules that prohibit general purpose programming languages from being distributed under the "terms of purchase". I believe that there are instances where people have reported compiling R in jail-broken devices, but the R Core is not particularly interested in getting into a license fight wih Apple.

Answer (score 1):

It's ported, but only to jail-broken devices - http://www.compmath.com/blog/2010/09/r-on-the-iphone/